# Setting the source of WPF Image control behind code

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, bitmapimage

Recently I've been strugling with setting the Setting the source of WPF Image control inside code.

I've tried something like:

```
Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/hrc.Hands;component/Images/BlueFolder.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

But it doesn't seem to work and thorws Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception. Here's the screenshot of the path to my image inside hierachy:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use..

```
var imageSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/" + "Images/BlueFolder.png", UriKind.Absolute);
Image.Source = imageSource;
```

Also, make sure that *BlueFolder.png* is set as a `Resource`. Right click the image, and select `Properties` to do this.

Comment: Maybe worth to note that this is called a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx), or more precisely a [Resource File Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly).